# Change style using JS

Tags: javascript

I have a CSS code:

```
.ui-dialog-buttonset .on{
        color: black;
        border-radius: 7px;

    }
```

And i want to set display = none for this using jquery:

```
$('#ui-dialog-buttonset .on').css('display', 'none');
```

It is not woring. 
What am I doing wrong ? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ui-dialog-buttonset` is a class, not an id. So select it using a period, not a hash:

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonset .on').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling jQuery to search for an element with id ui-dialog-buttonset because you used #. To select a class you must start with the "." like in:

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonset .on').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

`.ui-dialog-buttonset` - this is class
`#ui-dialog-buttonset` - this is ID

You are changing css of different item, which probably doesn't exists on your page.